# Weighted Average Cost across 2 tables power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am looking to calculate a weighted average cost of products that are on 2 separate tables within power BI. One for demand and one for supply. The common factor between the two tables is 'Datetime' that is every half hour period for the next few years. E.g.

```
Table A (Demand)
Total Value, Total Volume, datetime (half hourly)

Table B (supply)
Total Value, Total Volume, datetime (half hourly)
```

Within both of these tables, price can be calculated my just doing Value/Volume.

For the weighted average price within one table I have used a measure:

```
Weighted average price =
    sumx(table A, Table A[price] * Table A[Volume]) / sum(table A[Volume])
```

This seems to give me the correct weighted average price within each table. However if I try and calculate crystalized profit and loss which is the profit and loss between demand and supply `(P(d)-P(s))*(supply volume)` this doesn't work. I presume this is because sumx isn't smart enough to calculate the P/L for each half hour everyday and then add all these half hour P/L up to get total P/L.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.